# CefSharp - Capturing Resource Response Data

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to use [CefSharp](https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp) to visit a URL and capture all the resources retrieved during the loading of a given page (images, scripts, etc).  Presumably as a Stream or byte array per resource.

CefSharp provides the interface `IRequestHandler`.  You can create a class which implements this interface to respond to Request/Response events, notably

```
OnResourceResponse(
    IWebBrowser browser, 
    string url, 
    int status, 
    string statusText, 
    string mimeType, 
    System.Net.WebHeaderCollection headers)
```

The problem is this does not provide the response body in any way, just the url, headers, status, etc.

Is there a way to capture the data that the browser receives from the response or am I going to have to issue my own requests for the data using `HttpWebRequest`?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've found using schemeHandlers to be better in terms of control.
These allow you to trap and respond to requests for a given scheme.

```
public bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ISchemeHandlerResponse response, 
OnRequestCompletedHandler requestCompletedCallback)
```

The Response contains Headers/MimeType and Stream.

Comment: What the schema? Please give the full answer